# Unable to install pyhive in Cloudera quick start VM v5.13 running CentOS v6

Tags: python, hive, centos, centos6

I am using cloudera quick start vm version 5.13 which runs CentOS v6 on it. I want to use pyhive in the environment and referring to below link for installation of pyhive but I am unable to install any of the libraries given in link because I get an error this library doesn't exist. Please guide me on how can I install all required libraries before installing pyhive. thanks

https://dwgeek.com/guide-connecting-hiveserver2-using-python-pyhive.html/

**Installing gcc**
`sudo apt-get install gcc`

**Install Thrift**
`pip install thrift+`

**Install SASL**
`pip install sasl`

**Install thrift sasl**
`pip install thrift_sasl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take note, that `pyhive` saw no release since the end of 2018. This might be a sign it is no longer well maintained.

About your installation problem. For Linux there are different package formats and installers. The two most widely known are the ones for Ubuntu/Debian on the one side and Fedora/CentOS/Red Hat on the other side.

The installation instruction you refer to was written for the Debian familiy.

You need to translate the instructions for the Red Hat family.

That means you have to use the `yum install` command instead of the `apt-get install` command.

eg `sudo yum install gcc`

The other packages need to be installed via pip. `pip` should be already present on your system.

Please make sure to use a `virtualenv` for installation:
https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

One last note. CentOS 6 is also pretty old and only gets maintaince updates until November 2020.
https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product